# Can't extend data from Pin model

Tags: sqlite

My models.py looks like this.

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Pin(models.Model):
    proffession = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.proffession

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pin-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
        context = {
            'pins': Pin.objects.all(),
        }
        def get(self, request):
            users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
            return render(request, 'vlog/home.html')
        return render(request, 'vlog/home.html', context)

class PinListView(ListView):
    model = Pin
    template_name = 'vlog/home.html' # <app>/<model>_<view_type>.html
    context_object_name = 'pins'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
```

While extending data from Pin model. It doesn't provide any result. 
base.html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Available People</h3>
            {% for pin in pins %}
                <article class="media content-section">
                    <!-- <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}"> -->
                     <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="article-metadata">
                          <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'profileu' %}">{{ pin.username }}</a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="article-metadata">{{ pin.content }}</p>
                     </div>
                </article>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

How can I extend data from Pin Model in ListView. Please Share your suggestion

Comment: Hi Raj. Your question is pretty broad and there are too many information, too many code lines and no real focus. SO isn't a place to fix many code lines, but a place where you can find answers to very specific problems.